# Error: expanding `template_content` (azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment)

Tags: json, azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I´m trying to create some governance rules (Microsoft Defender for Cloud) using an ARM template through the azurerm-resource-group-template-deployment resource from the AzureRM Terraform provider, however I cannot find a way to handle that as it always complains about something different in the template content. This is the resource and template definition:

```
locals {
  scope_id   = var.scope_id
  scope_name = var.scope_name
  rules = {
    for rule in var.governance_rules : rule.priority == null ? 1 : rule.priority => {
      rule_suffix_name             = rule.rule_suffix_name,
      is_disabled                  = rule.is_disabled == null ? false : rule.is_disabled,
      owner_email_address          = rule.owner_email_address,
      priority                     = rule.priority == null ? 1 : rule.priority,
      condition_set                = rule.condition_set == null ? "[\"High\"]" : rule.condition_set,
      grace_period_enabled         = rule.grace_period_enabled == null ? true : rule.grace_period_enabled,
      disable_manager_notification = rule.disable_manager_notification == null ? true : rule.disable_manager_notification,
      disable_owner_notification   = rule.disable_owner_notification == null ? false : rule.disable_owner_notification,
      remediation_time_frame       = rule.remediation_time_frame == null ? "30.00:00:00" : rule.remediation_time_frame,
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "governance_rules" {
  for_each            = local.rules
  name                = lower("${local.scope_name}-${each.value.rule_suffix_name}-rule")
  resource_group_name = var.governance_rules_rg
  deployment_mode     = "Complete"
  template_content    = <<TEMPLATE
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Security/governanceRules",
      "apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
      "name": "${uuid()}",
      "scope": "${local.scope_id}",
      "properties": {
        "conditionSets": [
                    {
                        "conditions": [
                            {
                                "property": "properties.metadata.severity",
                                "value": "${jsonencode(each.value.condition_set)}",
                                "operator": "In"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
        "description": "Governance Rules",
        "displayName": "${jsonencode(lower("${local.scope_name}-${each.value.rule_suffix_name}-rule"))}",
        "excludedScopes": [],
        "governanceEmailNotification": {
          "disableManagerEmailNotification": ${jsonencode(each.value.disable_manager_notification)},
          "disableOwnerEmailNotification": ${jsonencode(each.value.disable_owner_notification)}
        },
        "includeMemberScopes": false,
        "isDisabled": ${jsonencode(each.value.is_disabled)},
        "isGracePeriod": ${jsonencode(each.value.grace_period_enabled)},
        "metadata": {},
        "ownerSource": {
          "type": "Manually",
          "value": "${jsonencode(each.value.owner_email_address)}"
        },
        "remediationTimeframe": "${jsonencode(each.value.remediation_time_frame)}",
        "rulePriority": ${jsonencode(each.value.priority)},
        "ruleType": "Integrated",
        "sourceResourceType": "Assessments"
      }
    }
  ],
}
TEMPLATE
}


variable "governance_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    condition_set                = optional(string)
    disable_manager_notification = optional(bool)
    disable_owner_notification   = optional(bool)
    grace_period_enabled         = optional(bool)
    is_disabled                  = optional(bool)
    owner_email_address          = string
    priority                     = optional(number)
    remediation_time_frame       = optional(string)
    rule_suffix_name             = string
  }))
}
```

The plan is generated accordinly, however it fails on the apply with the error below:

***│ Error: expanding `template_content`: invalid character '\\' after object key:value pair***

*│   with module.module_name.module.subscription_governance_rules.azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.governance_rules["1"],*

*│   on modules/governance-rules/main.tf line 20, in resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "governance_rules":*

*│   20: resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "governance_rules" {*

Initially I´ve tried without without the double quotes and without the jsonencode but even after they were added the problem remains. I´ve also tried many different combinations however the error is always the same and not that descriptive as it doesn´t tell even the line that is wrong.

I´ve made a request to the API to get the ARM template of an existing rule created manually from the Portal as reference. It looks like that:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/providers/microsoft.management/managementgroups/mgdefault/providers/microsoft.security/governancerules/<uuid>",
            "name": "<governance_rule_uuid>",
            "type": "microsoft.security/governancerules",
            "properties": {
                "tenantId": "<tenant_id>",
                "displayName": "temprule",
                "description": "description",
                "isDisabled": false,
                "ruleType": "Integrated",
                "rulePriority": 100,
                "remediationTimeframe": "30.00:00:00",
                "isGracePeriod": true,
                "ownerSource": {
                    "type": "Manually",
                    "value": "someone@contoso.com"
                },
                "conditionSets": [
                    {
                        "conditions": [
                            {
                                "property": "properties.metadata.severity",
                                "value": "[\"High\"]",
                                "operator": "In"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sourceResourceType": "Assessments",
                "excludedScopes": [],
                "includeMemberScopes": false,
                "governanceEmailNotification": {
                    "disableManagerEmailNotification": true,
                    "disableOwnerEmailNotification": true,
                    "emailNotificationDayOfWeek": "Sunday"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The resource format frm the documentation looks like that:

```
{
"type": "Microsoft.Security/governanceRules",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "string",
"scope": "string",
"properties": {
  "conditionSets": [ object ],
  "description": "string",
  "displayName": "string",
  "excludedScopes": [ "string" ],
  "governanceEmailNotification": {
    "disableManagerEmailNotification": "bool",
    "disableOwnerEmailNotification": "bool"
  },
  "includeMemberScopes": "bool",
  "isDisabled": "bool",
  "isGracePeriod": "bool",
  "metadata": {},
  "ownerSource": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "string"
  },
  "remediationTimeframe": "string",
  "rulePriority": "int",
  "ruleType": "string",
  "sourceResourceType": "Assessments"
}
```

}

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing content from the `template_content` until the error goes away. Then you've found where the problem is.

Comment: @lxop I´ve done that, the problem occurs with all string properties. I kept just the bool properties and it works, however when I try to add a variable to any string property it generates the error above.

Comment: Try creating the `template_content` in a `locals` block and passing it in. I don't expect that to change anything, but then you can print it as an output to see if the structure has anything interesting in it. In particular, check carefully that all quote marks are matched, aren't finished early, etc. I would copy the printed string into an editor with JSON highlighting - that would show up any problems. Also, just check what happens if you remove the comma after the last `]`

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create some governance rules using an ARM template through the azurerm-resource-group-template-deployment resource from the AzureRM Terraform provider. I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error you're encountering, "invalid character '' after object key:value pair," indicates that there might be an issue with escaping characters in your JSON template. To resolve this issue and provide you with a Terraform configuration that aligns with your requirements, I'll rewrite the Terraform code based on the provided ARM template.

For the configuration to be provisioned I followed the structure mentioned below with all relevant files.

```
my_terraform_project/
├── modules/
│   └── governance_rules/
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── variables.tf
│       └── outputs.tf
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── terraform.tfvars
└── provider.tf
```

**My terraform configuration files:**

**terraform_project/main.tf**

```
# Module for creating governance rules
module "governance_rules" {
  source = "./modules/governance_rules"

  scope_id             = var.scope_id
  scope_name           = var.scope_name
  governance_rules_rg  = var.governance_rules_rg

  governance_rules = var.governance_rules
}

# Define other resources or configurations as needed
```

**terraform_project/variables.tf**

```
# variables.tf

variable "scope_id" {
  description = "The ID of the scope."
  type        = string
}

variable "scope_name" {
  description = "The name of the scope."
  type        = string
}

variable "governance_rules_rg" {
  description = "The name of the resource group where governance rules will be deployed."
  type        = string
}

variable "governance_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    condition_set                = optional(list(string))
    disable_manager_notification = optional(bool)
    disable_owner_notification   = optional(bool)
    grace_period_enabled         = optional(bool)
    is_disabled                  = optional(bool)
    owner_email_address          = string
    priority                     = optional(number)
    remediation_time_frame       = optional(string)
    rule_suffix_name             = string
  }))
}



# Define other global variables if needed
```

**terraform_project/terraform.tfvars:**

```
scope_id             = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-***b-***a-2b83*****c23f"
scope_name           = "My Azure Subscription"
governance_rules_rg  = "v-sakavya"

governance_rules = [
  {
    rule_suffix_name             = "Rule1"
    owner_email_address          = "owner1@example.com"
    # Other rule properties
  },
  {
    rule_suffix_name             = "Rule2"
    owner_email_address          = "owner2@example.com"
    # Other rule properties
  },
  # Add more rules as needed
]
```

**terraform_project/modules/governance_rules/variables.tf:**

```
# modules/governance_rules/variables.tf

variable "scope_id" {
  description = "The ID of the scope."
  type        = string
}

variable "scope_name" {
  description = "The name of the scope."
  type        = string
}

variable "governance_rules_rg" {
  description = "The name of the resource group where governance rules will be deployed."
  type        = string
}


variable "governance_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    condition_set                = optional(list(string))
    disable_manager_notification = optional(bool)
    disable_owner_notification   = optional(bool)
    grace_period_enabled         = optional(bool)
    is_disabled                  = optional(bool)
    owner_email_address          = string
    priority                     = optional(number)
    remediation_time_frame       = optional(string)
    rule_suffix_name             = string
  }))
}

# Define other module-specific variables if needed
```

**terraform_project/modules/governance_rules/main.tf:**

```
# modules/governance_rules/main.tf
locals {
  filtered_rules = {
    for rule in var.governance_rules :
    rule.priority => {
      rule_suffix_name            = rule.rule_suffix_name
      is_disabled                 = coalesce(rule.is_disabled, false)
      owner_email_address         = rule.owner_email_address
      priority                    = coalesce(rule.priority, 1)
      condition_set               = coalesce(rule.condition_set, ["High"])
      grace_period_enabled        = coalesce(rule.grace_period_enabled, true)
      disable_manager_notification = coalesce(rule.disable_manager_notification, true)
      disable_owner_notification  = coalesce(rule.disable_owner_notification, false)
      remediation_time_frame      = coalesce(rule.remediation_time_frame, "30.00:00:00")
    } if rule.priority != null
  }
}




resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "governance_rules" {
  for_each            = local.filtered_rules  # Use local.filtered_rules here
  name                = lower("${var.scope_name}-${each.value.rule_suffix_name}-rule")
  resource_group_name = var.governance_rules_rg
  deployment_mode     = "Complete"
  template_content    = jsonencode({
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/governanceRules",
        "apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
        "name": "${uuid()}",
        "scope": var.scope_id,
        "properties": {
          "conditionSets": [
            {
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "property": "properties.metadata.severity",
                  "value": each.value.condition_set,
                  "operator": "In"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "description": "Governance Rules",
          "displayName": "${var.scope_name}-${each.value.rule_suffix_name}-rule",
          "excludedScopes": [],
          "governanceEmailNotification": {
            "disableManagerEmailNotification": each.value.disable_manager_notification,
            "disableOwnerEmailNotification": each.value.disable_owner_notification
          },
          "includeMemberScopes": false,
          "isDisabled": each.value.is_disabled,
          "isGracePeriod": each.value.grace_period_enabled,
          "metadata": {},
          "ownerSource": {
            "type": "Manually",
            "value": each.value.owner_email_address
          },
          "remediationTimeframe": each.value.remediation_time_frame,
          "rulePriority": each.value.priority,
          "ruleType": "Integrated",
          "sourceResourceType": "Assessments"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

**Output:**

Command `terraform_plan:`

[image]

Command **`terraform_apply -var-file .\terraform.tfvars`**

[image]